# Android Facebook Integration issue

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am having problem integrating facebook sdk into my app. I tried both the ways creating a jar file and importing it and refrencing the project into my current project.

I am having the following error:

1- From importing jar file: [2012-02-12 00:34:05 - FBtest] Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: AndroidManifest.xml
Origin 1: E:\Workspace\FBtest\bin\resources.ap_
Origin 2: E:\Workspace\FBtest\libs\fbs.jar

2- From refrencing the com_facebook_android, i am getting the follwing error, 02-12 00:31:05.308: E/AndroidRuntime(4738): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

explain out what prob u r getting while referencing facebook sdk as your lib project.. Also nice and very helful tutorial is given [here](http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application) to integrate Facebook sdk with your app..

Comment: 02-12 00:31:05.308: E/AndroidRuntime(4738): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.android.Facebook

This is comming when i refrece facebook sdk into my project

Comment: are you sure it is correctly referenced to your Project.  In eclipse right click on your project > Properties > Android > Library > Add  and then select facebook sdk project..   The error is coming up because the com.facebook.android.Facebook class is not available at runtime of your project

Comment: Thanks i did it actually copied the whole sdk into my project it solved

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue copy the android facebook sdk to your project :)